# Internal salesforce.com error while trying to access trigger.new context variable

Tags: event, after-trigger, gack, logout

I have created a trigger on the **LogoutEventStream** object, to perform the user logout-related functionality. When the user tries to log out from the application by clicking on the logout button, it is throwing an error [Internal salesforce.com error]. See the code below :

**LogoutEventStreamDomain class code -**

```java
 public with sharing class LogoutEventStreamDomain extends Domain {
 public LogoutEventStreamDomain(List<LogoutEventStream> logoutEventStreams) {
     super(logoutEventStreams);
 }

 public override void onAfterInsert() {
     try{
         LogoutEventStream logoutEvent = (LogoutEventStream)this.records[0];
         system.debug('logoutEvt::'+logoutEvent);
         User loggedOutUser = new UserSelector(false,false,false).getUsersByIdsWithDynamicFieldsForProfiles(
             new Set<String>{'PasswordAttemptTimeStack__c','SignaturePasswordAttemptCounter__c'},
             new Set<Id>{logoutEvent.UserId},
             new Set<String>{Constants.PROFILE_TRAKCEL_COMMUNITY_USER})[0];
         loggedOutUser.PasswordAttemptTimeStack__c = '';
         loggedOutUser.SignaturePasswordAttemptCounter__c = 0; 
         Data.modify(loggedOutUser,false,false,false);//No need of CRUD FLS as this is a system operation.
         system.debug('loggedOutUser1::'+loggedOutUser);
     }
     catch(Exception ex){
         Logger.getInstance().log(LogoutEventStreamDomain.class.getName(), ex, 'LogoutEventStreamDomain');
     }
 }
}
```

**Trigger code-**

```java
 trigger LogoutEventStreamTrigger on LogoutEventStream (after insert) {
     Domain.triggerHandler(LogoutEventStreamDomain.class);
 }
```

**Domain class code -**

```java
 public abstract with sharing class Domain {
 private static final Map<Type,Integer> TRIGGER_BYPASS = new Map<Type,Integer>();
 private static final Map<String,TriggerSettings__c> TRIGGER_SETTINGS= 
 TriggerSettings__c.getAll();
 
 private TriggerSettings__c mySettings;
 private Type myType;
 private SObjectType mySOType;
 private Schema.DescribeSObjectResult mySODescribe;
 protected Boolean enforceCRUD;
 protected Boolean enforceFLS;
 protected Boolean enforceShr;
 protected Boolean stateful;
 public  List<SObject> records {get; private set;} //

 protected Domain(List<SObject> records) {
     system.debug('domain==');
     init(records);
 }

 protected virtual void init(List<SObject> records) {       
     this.enforceCRUD    = true;
     this.enforceFLS     = true;
     this.enforceShr     = true;
     this.stateful       = true;
     this.records        = records;
     this.mySOType       = records.getSObjectType();
     this.mySODescribe   = this.mySOType.getDescribe();
 }

 /**
  * @return The SObjectType of the object that this Domain works with.
  */
 public Schema.SObjectType getSObjectType() {
     return this.mySOType;
 }
 
 /**
  * @return The API name of the object that this Domain works with.
  */
 public String getSObjectName() {
     return this.mySODescribe.getName();
 }
 
 /**
  * @return The API name of this domain class.
  */
 public String getDomainLayerName() {
     return this.myType.getName();
 }
 
 /**
  * @return true if this Domain should enforce CRUD by default.
  */
 public Boolean isEnforcingCRUD() {
     return this.enforceCRUD;
 }
 
 /**
  * @return true if this Domain should enforce FLS by default.
  */
 public Boolean isEnforcingFLS() {
     return this.enforceFLS;
 }
 
 /**
  * @return true if this Domain should enforce Sharing Rules by default.
  */
 public Boolean isEnforcingShr() {
     return this.enforceShr;
 }
 
 /*
     Sub-Types should override the following methods as needed
 */
 
 public virtual void onValidate() {}         
 public virtual void onAfterInsert() {}
 
 private void handleAfterInsert() {         
     onValidate();
     onAfterInsert();
 }
 
 public static void triggerHandler(Type handler) {
    try{
         system.debug('handler=='+handler);
         system.debug('Trigger.isExecuting=='+Trigger.isExecuting);
         if (handler == null || !Trigger.isExecuting) {
             return;
         }
         system.debug('Trigger.old=='+Trigger.old);
         List<SObject> data  = Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new;
         system.debug('data=='+data);
         
         Domain d        = (Domain)JSON.deserialize('{}', handler); // Ugly hack to instantiate an object instance that has no default constructor
         d.init(data);
         d.myType        = handler;
         d.mySettings    = TRIGGER_SETTINGS.get(d.myType.getName());
         if (d.mySettings == null) {
             d.mySettings = new TriggerSettings__c(
                 IsDisabled__c               = false,
                 IsBeforeInsertDisabled__c   = false,
                 IsBeforeUpdateDisabled__c   = false,
                 IsBeforeDeleteDisabled__c   = false,
                 IsAfterInsertDisabled__c    = false,
                 IsAfterUpdateDisabled__c    = false,
                 IsAfterDeleteDisabled__c    = false,
                 IsAfterUndeleteDisabled__c  = false
             );
         }
         if (!TRIGGER_BYPASS.containsKey(handler)) {
             TRIGGER_BYPASS.put(handler,0);
         }
         
         LimitsSnapshot ls = new LimitsSnapshot(d.myType.getName());
         
          if (Trigger.isAfter) {
             if (Trigger.isInsert && !d.isBypassed('AfterInsert')) {
                 system.debug('Trigger.isInsert187');
                 d.handleAfterInsert();
             } else if (Trigger.isUpdate && !d.isBypassed('AfterUpdate')) {
                 system.debug('Trigger.isUpdate190');
                 d.handleAfterUpdate();
             } else if (Trigger.isDelete && !d.isBypassed('AfterDelete')) {
                 d.handleAfterDelete();
             } else if(Trigger.isUnDelete && !d.isBypassed('AfterUndelete')) {
                 d.handleAfterUnDelete();
             }
         }
         Logger.getInstance().log(LogoutEventStreamDomain.class.getName(),'LogoutEventStreamDomain');
         ls.toLog();
     }
     catch(Exception ex){
         system.debug('Ex : ' + ex.getStackTraceString() + 'Msg: ' + ex.getMessage());
     }
   }
 }
```

It is failing in domain class at line 'List data  = Trigger.isDelete ? Trigger.old : Trigger.new;'. I put debug log for Trigger.new, at that line only I got this error.

See the screenshot below of debug logs,

[image]

It would be helpful if anyone can help me with this issue.

Comment: speculation - since `LogoutEventStream` is a PlatformEvent which was a feature introduced in the last few years, would updating the domain class version help?

Comment: Thank you so much, it has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

One of the first things to try when using standard SObjectTypes that are not of the run-of-the-mill variety is to consider whether your class is of an older version than when that SObjectType was introduced

`LogoutEventStream` is a Platform Event SObjectType and as such [was not introduced in Salesforce until Version 41](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_logouteventstream.htm).  This causes issues with the describe methods such as this one:

```
this.mySODescribe   = this.mySOType.getDescribe();
```

as the describe methods are version-specific - they will only return describe info for the object as of the class's version

Update your `Domain` class and any other class that references that SObjectType to at least V41